# boost asio error category is null

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio

In my asio based application I have problems with the error handling. I use asio single-threaded/single io_service with the async_read / async_write functions, and when the error-code passed to me in the completion handler is not null, any call to its .message() method results in a segfault, because the error-category pointer points to null. However, the actual value is always correct.

Weirdly I am not able to reproduce this in a test application. This is essentially what I'm doing, but in case of an error, calling message() here works as expected:

```
void do_write(std::shared_ptr<std::vector<unsigned char>> , std::shared_ptr<boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket> );

void do_read(std::shared_ptr<std::vector<unsigned char>> buf, std::shared_ptr<boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket> sock)
{
   boost::asio::async_read(*sock, boost::asio::buffer(*buf), boost::asio::transfer_exactly(100000),
                           [sock, buf](const boost::system::error_code& ec, std::size_t bytes)
   {
      std::cout << "read\n";
      if (ec) {
         std::cout << ec.message() << std::flush;
      } else {
         do_write(buf, sock);
      }
   });
}

void do_write(std::shared_ptr<std::vector<unsigned char>> buf, std::shared_ptr<boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket> sock)
{
   boost::asio::async_write(*sock, boost::asio::buffer(*buf), [sock, buf](const boost::system::error_code& ec, std::size_t bytes)
   {
      std::cout << "write\n";
      if (ec) {
         std::cout << ec.message() << std::flush;
      } else {
         do_read(buf, sock);
      }
   });
}

int main()
{
   auto buf = std::make_shared<std::vector<unsigned char>>(100000);

   unsigned short port = 1113;
   boost::asio::io_service ios;
   boost::asio::ip::tcp::acceptor acptr {ios, boost::asio::ip::tcp::endpoint{boost::asio::ip::tcp::v4(), port}};

   auto socket = std::make_shared<boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket>(acptr.get_io_service());
   acptr.async_accept(*socket, [socket, buf](const boost::system::error_code& ec)
   {
      do_read(buf, socket);
   });
   ios.run();
}
```

I do not think it is a problem with lifetimes of my application, AddressSanitizer does not find any potential errors and I can shift hundreds of megabytes of data without any problems. Also if I just uncomment the call to message(), the server continues to run fine and correctly handles new connections. Anyway, here is the callstack when the crash occurs:

https://gist.github.com/mariusherzog/82f24caf9eea4d94946706aa8c025ef1
The category points to null from frame 11 upwards.

I use linux with boost 1.62 with clang 3.9.1 and gcc 5.4.0

Answer (score 1):

The only thing I can think of is right now that a piece of code initializes as part of constructing global static data. If it grabs a category reference at that time and there are multiple translation units, the category instance might not have been constructed yet.

This situation is affectionately referred to as the [Static Initialization Order Fiasco](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/ctors#static-init-order).

---

*Other than that, the converse comes to mind (the global category has been destructed). This seems a little less likely because 1. you'd have realized it happens at shutdown 2. references don't usually become null in such a scenario - although an implementation might*

Comment: Thanks for the tip. The error category (get_misc_category) is accessed via a Meyer's singleton, and if I put a breakpoint there, the actual instance is all null in memory from the beginning on. Might this be a bug in asio?

Comment: Also it is called multiple times in my application, seemingly caused by different translation units...

Comment: It doesn't really matter whether you access it via a Meyer's singleton: more importantly, `get_misc_category()` ***is***  itself a Meyer's singleton. If that goes wrong the only thing I can really imagine going wrong is runtime linking.

Comment: Perhaps multiple copies of the singleton are in different modules, and somehow the one in the "extra" module is not getting initialized. I don't actually see how this could legally happen, there might be a (runtime) linker bug. Are you using LTO? Are you perhaps linking Boost System statically into a shared library? See also this related question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43011009/85371 and this excellent talk: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=w7ZVbw2X-tE

Comment: By the way "it's all null in memory fromt the beginning on" is how it's supposed to be, until `get_misc_category()` is first called, of course. The TL;DR of the above links is that it _is_ quite possible to get multiple copies of `get_misc_category()` so identical categories compare un-equal when compared by address. However, what I cannot see explain is why any single copy of `get_misc_category()` would have it's initialization guard malfunction so that the function-local static never gets initialized. I do feel that that takes a linker bug.

Comment: Note: When using c++03, Meyer's singleton is not thread safe, so that would make using `get_misc_category()` a potential data race in c++03 depending on how you use it.

Comment: I am using C++11 and I am linking boost dynamically. However I have all my network related code in a library which I link statically to the "main" application, but this should not be a problem?

Comment: @MariusHerzog depending on whether you rely on categories having a fixed address this could be an issue. However like I said I don't think it _should_ explain a null-reference/uninitialized global data. This was all already above. If you want to know how it could be a problem, follow the links, otherwise, look at the likely culprits (name-map your binaries, look for conflicts, perhaps `nm -C`; disable some optimization flags, inspect the generated assembly to find the bug (`objdump -S -t` e.g.)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158478/discussion-between-sehe-and-marius-herzog).